# Connect two users using server

Tags: networking, p2p

How can I connect two clients connected to TCP server so they will be able to send packets to each other (they don't have public IP)?

Comment: your question is too vague to be answered. Try providing some more details, like the technology you are using, the OS environment (if relevant), what they have to achieve, any constraints, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this and it is implemented in many popular applications like google talk, skype etc.

### Method 1

Create a server application that can take in the packet from client 1 and forward it to client 2 and vice versa.

### Method 2

Both client 1 and client 2 connect to the server and the server will provide IP address of client 1 to client 2 or vice versa. This is done in some peer to peer softwares.

Provide more details like what is the programming language, exact scenario etc so that we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add tags. C# - FileSending application